# Meaning of postgresql log "using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding"

Tags: debian-wheezy, postgresql-9.1

I have a Postgresql 9.1+134wheezy4 running on Debian 7 Wheezy. From 2015-02-07 on (I guess it has been backported then, see below) I regularly see the following line in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log`:

```
2015-02-07 11:08:33 CET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
```

I shows a up few times a day, nothing spectacular or to worry about. But I don't get the meaning of the line and couldn't find documentation about it. It is mentioned in the changelogs for [9.3.6](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-6.html) and [9.4.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4-1.html):

> - Change "pgstat wait timeout" warning message to be LOG level, and rephrase it to be more understandable (Tom Lane)
>
>   This message was originally thought to be essentially a can't-happen case, but it occurs often enough on our slower buildfarm members to be a nuisance. Reduce it to LOG level, and expend a bit more effort on the wording: it now reads "using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding".

Unfortunately, it does not explain the meaning. I also had `WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout` until it changed in February as often as the new message. The information on the log line are also not helpful/constructive. A frequent advice is to restart the server or to remove the shared memory segment.

These are the logs for a postgresql restart:

```
2015-05-25 17:01:39 CEST LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2015-05-25 18:00:04 CEST LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2015-05-25 18:00:04 CEST LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2015-05-25 18:00:04 CEST LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2015-05-25 18:00:04 CEST LOG:  shutting down
2015-05-25 18:00:04 CEST LOG:  database system is shut down
2015-05-25 18:00:06 CEST LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-05-25 18:00:04 CEST
2015-05-25 18:00:06 CEST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2015-05-25 18:00:06 CEST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-05-25 18:00:07 CEST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Could it mean that the statistics collector is somehow broken or misconfigured? What is the reason for this behaviour and how can it be avoided?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648029/postgres-replication-incomplete-startup-packet

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh So you think I should do `select pg_start_backup('initial_backup');` wait a bit and then `select pg_stop_backup();`?

Comment: Massively excessive load is the only time I've seen this. Do you have many thousands of active connections on a small machine?

Comment: I only search for you and recommend you search before any post.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have nearly zero requests and 75% of total memory is free all the time.

Comment: My Postgres 9.4.4 on Cygwin is doing this too, spamming my terminal with `WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Device or resource busy` and one line of the error in the title. It is currently idle yet I get this error.